# Google maps application open directly on place details screen

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm creating hybrid mobile application in ionic framework and need to use google maps application to display google place details. I'm wondering wheter is it possible to display place details directly from code (to display directly image2 instead of image1 - image to is displayed when clicked on place name at bottom):

here's a code sample how I am calling google maps app:

```
url = "geo:?q=" + encodeURIComponent(placeName);  
window.open(url, "_system", 'location=no');  
//url = geo:?q=Crveni%20pevac
```

image1:
[image: image1]
image2
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an implementation of Google Place Details and Google Place Photos which are mentioned in this [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details). There's also a sample app on [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places) to get you started.